# How to make a single column 10 row data set from two column 5 row data set

Tags: python

I have a python script to does a **count of date of month** in one additional column and a **count of day of week** in another column.

What I want to do is combine the two sets of COUNT results and sum them into distinct rows with a key and a count value and calculate the percentage value then sort in descending order.

Here are some results:

```
[(22, 8), (24, 1), (23, 1)]
[(Friday, 2), (Monday, 4), (Thursday, 2), (Tuesday, 1), (Wednesday, 1)]
```

What I would expect is:

[image]

Comment: The two lines you provided aren't valid Python (unless you have variables called `Friday`, etc.) - are the names of the days supposed to be strings? What type of data structure do you want the result to be? A list of dictionaries? A dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming we name your first list `l1`:

```
>>> l1 = [(22, 8), (24, 1), (23, 1)]
```

and your second list `l2`, with keys as strings to become valid Python code:

```
>>> l2 = [('Friday', 2), ('Monday', 4), ('Thursday', 2), ('Tuesday', 1
), ('Wednesday', 1)]
```

we can start by merging these two lists in one list `l` with:

```
>>> l = l1 + l2
>>> l
[(22, 8), (24, 1), (23, 1), ('Friday', 2), ('Monday', 4), ('Thursday', 2), ('Tuesday', 1), ('Wednesday', 1)]
```

Then, we can create a single list `l0` containing all the values you want with the following, rather complicated, list comprehension:

```
>>> l0 = [(k, v, (v / sum([p[1] for p in l]) * 100)) for k, v in l]
>>> l0
[(22, 8, 40.0), (24, 1, 5.0), (23, 1, 5.0), ('Friday', 2, 10.0), ('Monday', 4, 20.0), ('Thursday', 2, 10.0), ('Tuesday', 1, 5.0), ('Wednesday', 1, 5.0)]
```

To make it a bit clearer, the sum could be put in an intermediate variable:

```
>>> total = sum([p[1] for p in l])
```

so the list comprehension is reduced to:

```
>>> l0 = [(k, v, (v / total * 100)) for k, v in l]
```

Finally, we can sort this last list in descending order based on the percentage of each tuple in the list `l0` with:

```
>>> sorted(l0, key=lambda t: t[2], reverse=True)
[(22, 8, 40.0), ('Monday', 4, 20.0), ('Friday', 2, 10.0), ('Thursday', 2, 10.0), (24, 1, 5.0), (23, 1, 5.0), ('Tuesday', 1, 5.0), ('Wednesday', 1, 5.0)]
```

Comment: and then you sort that list with `sorted(tlist, key=lambda x: x[2], reverse=True)`

Comment: Thanks, just added this last sorting step.

Comment: that is awesome! thanks @seldomspeechless for this, will try it out now

Comment: thanks @etog for the sort too

Comment: that worked a treat :)

Comment: @etog my sort didn't work though, it shows as `[(22, 8, 40.0), (23, 1, 5.0), (24, 1, 5.0), ('Friday', 2, 10.0), ('Monday', 4, 20.0), ('Thursday', 2, 10.0), ('Tuesday', 1, 5.0), ('Wednesday', 1, 5.0)]` and I used `sorted(rank_values_perc, key=lambda t: t[2], reverse=True)`

Comment: The `sorted` function does not modify you list 'in-place'. Instead, it returns another list, which is a sorted copy of the list you pass to `sorted`. So the sorted list is accessible by doing `sortedList = sorted(...)`. You could also sort your list in-place by doing `l0.sort(key=lambda t: t[2], reverse=True)`. See https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html for more details on sorting.